# How to copy file from local machine to SFTP server using Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, sftp

I am building a Jenkins Pipeline where my jenkins is installed on my local windows machine. The war is build and stored in my local system. As part of the deployment cycle followed in project where I work, am supposed to copy it to SFTP server to some location. Am not able to figure this out. Can someone please help.

Comment: Just an observation, but it's generally bad practice to deploy artifacts built on the same instance (your local system) where the development occurs. Too much chance for "cross-contamination" that make the artifact non-reproducible: cuncontrolled files, common repository, etc. Best to build on separate, dedicated hw, w/proper configuration controls.

Comment: You say "you found a way". Can you either mark one of the responses as accepted, or answer your own Q with explanation. That's how S/O works: collaboration and sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

There are several Jenkins plugins which may work, eg: [Publish over FTP](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ftp/), [Publish over SSH](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/). Similarly named [FTP Publisher](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ftppublisher/) and [SCP Publisher](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scp/) have vulnerabilities and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

So, what problem? You can use pscp and psftp. This tools are very customizable(options) and light weight. Open source.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Download it and write a bat file to send package to server. Then call this bat file from Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem is am new to this game and am trying to learn. Would be really helpful if maybe you can add a snippet from Jenkins file that explains it better.

Comment: Please attach here the Pipeline file. The I can help you

Comment: I found a way. Thanks. :)